# How to make a site with, WordPress handling the UI and ReactJS handling the Front-End logic

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

[ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) allows us to create user interfaces. [Word Press](https://wordpress.org/) allows us to build websites, whose buttons, list, color, styles can be customized, with a minimal(to no) knowledge in coding.

I have a web site up and running with ReactJS, where the backend is done in NodeJS and ExpressJS.
But the UI is just a basic one.

I want to build a new site where WordPress handles the UI, like the color, style, size etc of components like Button, Tables, List, headings etc and a person with minimal-to no knowldge in coding should be able to drag and drop or customize the website UI, and the ReactJS should handle all the front-end logic and the backend would be handled by NodeJS and ExpressJS.

Is it possible to do so?? Which frameword or word-press plugin should I use. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Good day, Hari.
I can try to help you.
1)Wordpress has now Gutenberg block editor withs use React to create UI logic.

[image]
So its very easy to create buttons with colors and style the text in 3 clicks.
At the backend we still have wordpress PHP scripts.

2)Another solution is that Wordpress allow to include your React code to your theme with webpack file

[image]
please follow this link to see Demo theme

https://github.com/zgordon/twentytwenty-react/

3)Next solution is Frontify its a framework to connect Wordpress + React
https://frontity.org/

[image]

The Let me know if it helps you.
Thanks